# How can I run tests that are in a different folder than tests/ in Ember CLI?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Ember CLI automatically runs all the tests that are written in files named:

`tests/**/*[-_]test.js`

Is there any way to run tests that aren't under the `tests/` directory?

Thank you!

Edit: Why do I need this? I'm writing a program that runs external tests inside Ember projects. I don't want to have to copy the tests inside these projects.

Comment: Try playing with the _testem.json_ config file: https://github.com/airportyh/testem/blob/master/docs/config_file.md. The _src_files_ setting looks like something you could alter for this.

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. I even tried adding "*.js" to src_files.

Comment: It seems the problem is in the build phase. Broccoli is only selecting the files under tests/ and after everything is built testem runs whatever Broccoli built.

Comment: Not sure how you would go about it without having to modify internals, I am not sure but I believe [this](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/master/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js#L700) is where broccoli gets the test directory. Will test it out once I have the time.

Comment: From what I saw yesterday, `this.tests` is just a boolean flag, `true` by default. See [this line](https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/blob/2d94a13ce874f37b45b7d31c1787981c9eab31a9/lib/broccoli/ember-app.js#L1121). My only hope is to add some code to Brocfile.js that adds the additional tests folder to `app.toTree()` before exporting it from the file. But it's hard because the tests have to be added to the same output file that the standard tests/ are added to.